# Attempting to use trp package to process textract output and getting key errors

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-textract

Using
`with open('C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\1.json', 'r') as file: data = json.load(file)`
I load the json file in and then use
`doc = t1.Document(t2.TDocumentSchema().dump(data))`
to load the json into trp so that it can easily be processed to extract table and query values from the json. Unfortunately it gives me a key error that the page['Blocks']: gives a key error. When testing the data set and printing data["Blocks"] it is able to print the data just fine which makes me wonder why the library is having issues with loading the json. When checking the debugger the object it loads/uses seems to be empty which confuses me on why it isn't loading the parsed.

Looking at the library the function that it is referencing is

```
def _parseDocumentPagesAndBlockMap(self):

    blockMap = {}

    documentPages = []
    documentPage = None
    for page in self._responsePages:
        for block in page['Blocks']:
            if('BlockType' in block and 'Id' in block):
                blockMap[block['Id']] = block

            if(block['BlockType'] == 'PAGE'):
                if(documentPage):
                    documentPages.append({"Blocks" : documentPage})
                documentPage = []
                documentPage.append(block)
            else:
                documentPage.append(block)
    if(documentPage):
        documentPages.append({"Blocks" : documentPage})
    return documentPages, blockMap`
```

I have looked at the library and I can't entirely tell how to approach this issue as according to the aws and github sources I've found it should work fine without any changes. If I could have help figuring out why this doesn't work I would greatly appreciate it.

I have tried debugging, I have tried checking whether the json was formatted correctly, and I tried to see if there was an issue with the library. The json validates fine and can be read according to the key that the library is having issues with when checking the loaded json.